# jQuery event on nested future object

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have web page which makes some ajax calls and loads the following HTML:

```
<span class="actions">
    <a class="delete" href="/delete/1">Delete</a>
    <a class="edit" href="/edit/1">Edit</a>
</span>
```

The following javascript should attach event handlers to the future objects:

```
$('.actions').live('ready', initFileActions);
var initFileActions = function (options) {
    alert('action called');
    $('.delete', this).click (function (e) {
        alert ('delete called');
    });
   $('.edit', this).click (function (e) {
        alert ('edit called');
    });
    return $(this);
}
```

The above code calls the first alert ('action called') fine, however it's not calling the second alert ('delete called'), could anyone please help how can I call the second alert in the above code.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you're listening to ready on a anchors as they have no ready event - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers. I think Khanh TO snippet will help you here.

Answer (score 1):

`.live` is deprecated and should use `.on`.
Try:

```
$(document).on('click','.actions .delete' initFileActions);
var initFileActions = function (options) {
    alert ('delete called');
    return $(this);
}
```

Comment: Basically in action class, there can be several actions like 'edit', 'delete', 'add', so is there a simpler way to just call $(document).on() once, instead of $(document).on('click', 'action delete',func()); $(document).on('click', 'action add',func()); $(document).on('click', 'action edit',func())? I wanted to do something like $(document).on('click', 'action',fund()) and then in func() I wanted to further add events to click click event but that's not working. It only works if the content already exist but as in  my case contents are coming from ajax call, so it's failing..

Comment: @Imran Imtiaz: I don't see benefits and why you have to do it that way, you have to attach so many event handlers.